# What's the most appropriate markup for an HTML user avatar?

Tags: html, accessibility, semantic-markup

I'm curious if people have thoughts on what the most appropriate and semantic HTML markup would be for a user avatar, i.e. an image of a user, labeled by their name and perhaps some other descriptive information.

My original thought was just an `img` tag followed by a span of text. The proximity of image to label *seems* like a sufficient connection between image and text to semantically correlate them.

My colleague, however, mentioned the `figure` element, and that this might be an appropriate use, with the `figcaption` serving as the name and descriptive text.

Comment: Is this avatar only going to be used once on the page? I ask because if it is to be used as part of a list of users or chat then that impacts the advice given. If not then 90% of the time the answer would be to dynamically name it '[User Name] User Avatar' as alt text on the image for example, no need to over complicate things.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The question has to do with the appropriate surrounding markup that ties an image of a person with a text node describing them, regardless of the context. It’s more of a philosophical question that will advise some UI documentation I’m creating for a dev team, so I’m looking for a more general best-practice suggestion on what is most semantic and accessible for this scenario. In the absence of a descriptive text, the alt attribute would be sufficient, but in this case there is adjacent text describing the image, so the alt attribute is not appropriate. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

A `figure` with `figcaption` would be a reasonable choice (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) for more details on the semantics of `figure`).

You could also use a `p`, which is generally very useful for marking up phrasing content. This quote from MDN on `p` illuminates its often overlooked usefulness:

> The HTML `<p>` element represents a paragraph. Paragraphs are usually represented in visual media as blocks of text separated from adjacent blocks by blank lines and/or first-line indentation, *but HTML paragraphs can be any structural grouping of related content, such as images or form fields*.

So `p`'s semantic meaning is not isolated to paragraphs of text. It is, in fact, the workhorse container for phrasing content. And further, about the accessibility of `p`:

> Breaking up content into paragraphs helps make a page more accessible. Screen-readers and other assistive technology provide shortcuts to let their users skip to the next or previous paragraph, letting them skim content like how white space lets visual users skip around.

[MDN docs reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p)

`p` tags act as accessible groupings for any phrasing content:

> Phrasing content defines the text and the mark-up it contains. Runs of phrasing content make up paragraphs.
>
> Elements belonging to this category are `<abbr>`, `<audio>`, `<b>`, `<bdo>`, `<br>`, `<button>`, `<canvas>`, `<cite>`, `<code>`, `<command>`, `<data>`, `<datalist>`, `<dfn>`, `<em>`, `<embed>`, `<i>`, `<iframe>`, `<img>`, `<input>`, `<kbd>`, `<keygen>`, `<label>`, `<mark>`, `<math>`, `<meter>`, `<noscript>`, `<object>`, `<output>`, `<picture>`, `<progress>`, `<q>`, `<ruby>`, `<samp>`, `<script>`, `<select>`, `<small>`, `<span>`, `<strong>`, `<sub>`, `<sup>`, `<svg>`, `<textarea>`, `<time>`, `<var>`, `<video>`, `<wbr>` and plain text (not only consisting of white spaces characters).

[MDN Docs reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories)